# Highcharts: Show navigator range in subtitle

Tags: highcharts, subtitle

I have a small problem (i hope it is small) with highcharts.
My target is, to show the chosen min/max range from the navigation to the subtitle. 
But I have no idea how to do this.
Here a sample picture

[image: Image 1]
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `chart.render` event to achieve this in the following way:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    render: function(){
      this.setSubtitle(
        {text: 
          '<b>From:</b> ' +
          (new Date(this.xAxis[0].getExtremes().userMin).toLocaleString()) +
          ' <b>To: </b>' + 
          (new Date(this.xAxis[0].getExtremes().userMax).toLocaleString())
        }
      )
    }
  }
},
```

This will give you a min/max when the chart is loaded, and when user selects their interval.

The timeformat can be changed of course, I used `.toLocaleString()` because it is easy.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/37bp1qpc/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.events.render

Comment: This works for me, perfect. Thank you very much. I hope i can help the community next time too. Thumbs up!